# How to instantiate superclass template with own type?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have many classes A which are quite similar except for their data structure, so I'd like to move the common stuff into a base template B.  The problem is that the template parameter is part of the inheriting class, so it comes after the point where I need to pass it to the template.  How can this be achieved without moving X out of A (trying to maintain encapsulation)?

```
template<class X>
class B {
    int somefunction( X a );
};

class A : public B<X> {
  public:
    struct X { // different in each class A
        int x;
    };
};
```

NB: A's "members" need to be delegated to a central container for architecture reasons, so I need this sub-struct.  Yes, I know, I don't like it either, but that can't be changed.

Comment: If `X` is public inside `A` what are you encapsulating?

Comment: If `X` is public move it outside of `A` and simple use `B` with the different structures. no need for inheritance to complicate things.

Comment: I understand encapsulation as putting together what belongs together, not as hiding something.

Answer (score 2):

That cannot be done, as at the point where the bases are instantiated, the type is still incomplete, and the nested type is not defined. What is the problem that you are trying to solve? There might be simpler solutions than what you are trying.

Comment: The classes A are generated, and 80% identical.  Many of the methods don't care what's inside X, so they would fit nicely into a base class.  The same applies for the mechanism which delegates storage of X to the central container.

Comment: Can you change the code generation tool to generate the nested type somewhere else?

Comment: I could, but it seems kinda dirty to have my own struct defined outside of me.  That's what I meant with encapsulation.

Comment: @Daniel: Designing is finding compromises to adapt to the needs and the tools. You can do different things, you can for example, *encapsulate* differently (have an outer class/namespaces of which these two are nested classes), you can provide the nested type as a nested type of a trait-class... what you cannot do is the code in the question, since the language does not allow it. Note that what you call *encapsulation* is not what is usually called by that name, and in changing your definition you might be applying common sense phrases with the wrong meanings